# How to register a callback in server to receive data with Android?

Tags: android, sockets, callback

Is there a (more modern) way (besides using sockets) to register a callback method to listen for data?

I'd like to have my app register itself with it's IP and a callback method name. The server would then send data back - much like Whatsapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly; besides sockets there are alternatives for pushing messages to Android devices, particularly "Cloud Messaging": https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ .

If you just want to implement TCP or UDP-based communications by implementing your own server, sockets are not "outdated" (what do you mean with "modern"?). You can write your own re-usable Server/Client classes that ease the registering of callbacks for incoming connections/packets.

If you google a bit, you will also find frameworks that offer message-based communications facilities you are searching for, e.g.
http://www.binpress.com/app/chat-messaging-sdk-for-android/2326 .

P.S.: I suggest you reformulate the title of your question, because it seems not to be about callback registering itself!

Comment: May question was unclear indeed. I didnt know how to ask. Thanks for point out some alternatives. I'll take a look.